# I want to bind kivy list-item with on_press:root.manager.current = 'screen1'

Tags: kivy, kivymd, onpress

I am a beginner (Sorry for clumsy codes).
I want to make codes such that whenever I click a menu icon in header, navbar toggle out. And list of items appears in the navbar. (this works)
And when I click the item in navbar, it brings me to another screen (this doesn't work).
Below are the codes. It shows 'NoneType' has no attribute of 'current'

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivymd.theming import ThemableBehavior
from kivymd.uix.list import MDList
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager

navigation_helper = """
MDScreen:
    MDNavigationLayout:
        ScreenManager:
            MDScreen:
                MDBoxLayout:
                    orientation: 'vertical'
                    MDToolbar:
                        title: 'Title'
                        left_action_items: [["menu", lambda x: nav_drawer.set_state("open")]]
                        elevation:10
                    Widget:
            Screen1:

        MDNavigationDrawer:
            id: nav_drawer
            ContentNavigationDrawer:
                id: content_drawer
                orientation: 'vertical'
                padding: "8dp"
                spacing: "8dp"
                
                AnchorLayout:
                    anchor_x: "left"
                    size_hint_y: None
                    height: avatar.height
                    
                    Image:
                        id: avatar
                        size_hint: None, None
                        size: "180dp", "100dp"
                        source: "logo.png"

                ScrollView:
                    DrawerList:
                        id: md_list

                        MDList:
                            OneLineIconListItem:
                                text: "Screen 1"
                                on_press: root.manager.current = 'screen1'
                                IconLeftWidget:
                                    icon: "account-multiple"
                                    
<Screen1>:
    name: 'screen1'
    MDLabel:
        text: 'Profile'
        halign: 'center'
"""

class Screen1(Screen):
    pass


sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(Screen1(name='screen1'))


class ContentNavigationDrawer(BoxLayout):
    pass


class DrawerList(ThemableBehavior, MDList):
    pass


class NavBar(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        screen = Builder.load_string(navigation_helper)
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = 'Indigo'
        return screen

    def on_start(self):
        pass


NavBar().run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default `root` is `None`, so when you write `on_press: root.manager.current = 'screen1'` it raises the expected error, `AttributeError`.

But also note that even if you remove it, you will get another error `NameError` as you've not given any reference to 'manager'.

Thus the changes you need,

```py
    MDNavigationLayout:
        ScreenManager:
            id: manager # Use it as id keeping the name as it is.
            MDScreen:
```

and also,

```py
                        MDList:
                            OneLineIconListItem:
                                text: "Screen 1"
                                on_press: manager.current = 'screen1'
                                IconLeftWidget:
                                    icon: "account-multiple"
```

Comment: OMG! Thanks alot. You solved my problem. Thanks very much